# @JsonProperty with Boolean and String

Tags: java, json, jackson

How to deserialize @JsonProperty with Boolean and String return types.

"data" returns boolean

```
"Info": {
  "type": "TEST",
  "data": true
},
```

"data" returns array

```
"Info": {
  "type": "TEST",
  "data": {"index": [{"a1": 4,"a2": 0,}]}
},
```

Comment: Can you please share your java code? So what you want is to serialize the same java property to boolean or string depending on some condition?

Comment: Exactly, so in the Json response "data" sometimes returns a boolean or string. I know this can be done using jackson custom deserializer.

Answer (score 0):

define data to Object.

```
private Object data;
```

then you have to check type like this

```
if(data instanceof String) {
    //  ...
}else if(data instanceof Boolean) {
    //  ...
}else if(data instanceof Array) {
    //  ...
}
```